# Display problems when booting into Linux

Tags: display, external-display, opensuse

I bought a new Samsung monitor and booted into Linux and the display was horrible (extremely bright and poor contrast). I tried to change settings but I was not satisfied with the ouput. I then booted back into windows and used Samsung's Magictune and the display was excellent. I booted back into LInux and the display is a mess again. I believe this could be with the X subsystem but I don't know the fundamentals to tweak X. Can someone provide the high-level guidelines to troubleshoot this issue.

I run openSuse with XFCE.
External monitor : Samsung 22''

Comment: I suspect you did, but you did try to reinstall the correct drivers into the Linux partition, right? Also, an extremely bright, poorly contrasted display can be caused either by the screen's settings themselves (the buttons on it) or by the video output's settings, that you change using your mouse and keyboard. Which one is it?

Comment: @Ariane: I very much doubt he's fiddling with the monitor buttons in between booting into Windows and Linux. Clearly he needs a Linux alternative to MagicTune.

Comment: It seems MagicTune uses the [DDC/CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel#DDC.2FCI) standard to communicate with the monitor. Unfortunately the only Linux alternative I found was [DDCcontrol](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net), but it was last updated way back in 2006. Still, give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: @Karan I said that because I vaguely remember experiencing a monitor that "auto-adjusted" itself at boot, wrongly, depending on the conditions.

Comment: @Karan while the presence of Magictune in Linux would be awesome, I believe it should be the job of Samsung to write it. I tried a nasty trick to run it using mono but it is obviously not CLI compliant. And, No, I am not monkeying with buttons inbetween boot.

Comment: @Ariane yes what you say makes ton of sense; The monitor is just too dumb to adjust itself,but the OS could load a wrong driver for the graphics card. I explored the X11 logs and figured out that it loads the generic intel driver for display,which is good. I am currently tinkering to load a specific Mobile chipset driver from Intel as my laptop uses a mobile graphic card.

Comment: "I believe it should be the job of Samsung to write it" - Absolutely, I agree with you 100%! Either that, or they should allow all OSD functions to be accessed via actual physical buttons. Anything else is just cheating the customer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a newer [DDC Control](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol) version you can try ([guide](http://developers-club.com/posts/94990/)).

If you have a nvidia graphics card you might need a [workaround](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/572292/linux/-solved-does-gddccontrol-work-for-anyone-here-nvidia-i2c-monitor-display-ddc/3#4308840).